# Get parts of URL in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, url

I am just wondering what the best way of extracting "parameters" from an URL would be, using PHP.

If I got the URL:

```
http://example.com/user/100
```

How can I get the user id (100) using PHP?

Answer (score 19):

To be thorough, you'll want to start with [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
$parts=parse_url("http://example.com/user/100");
```

That will give you an array with a handful of keys.  The one you are looking for is `path`.

Split the path on `/` and take the last one.

```
$path_parts=explode('/', $parts['path']);
```

Your ID is now in `$path_parts[count($path_parts)-1]`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php),  i.e.:

```
$parts = parse_url("http://x.com/user/100");
$path_parts= explode('/', $parts[path]);
$user = $path_parts[2];
echo $user; 
# 100
```

`parse_url()`

> This function parses a URL and returns an associative array containing
>   any of the various components of the URL that are present. The values
>   of the array elements are not URL decoded.
>
> This function is notmeant to validate the given URL, it only breaks it
>   up into the above listed parts. Partial URLs are also
>   accepted, parse_url() tries its best to parse them correctly.

Answer (score 3):

```
$url = "http://example.com/user/100";
$parts = Explode('/', $url);
$id = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
```

Comment: He didn't ask for the current file, he says he has a URL.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but I think the following is a better answer:
`basename(dirname(__FILE__))`