# return specific part of URL

Tags: php

I want return specific part of URL by php. for example if URL is :

```
http://website.com/part1/part2/part3/detail/page_id/number/page/2
```

or

```
http://website.com/part1/part2/part3/detail/page_id/number/page/3
```

I want return number.

is it okay?

```php
$pattern = "/\d+$/";
$input = "http://website.com/part1/part2/part3/detail/page_id/number/page/2";
preg_match($pattern, $input, $matches);
$post_id = $matches[8];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985505/get-part-of-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use it:

```
return $id3 = $parts[count($parts) - 3];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the id would be in `$matches[0]`.
But this regex pattern would match any url with a number at the end. E.g.

```
http://differentdomain.com/whatever/7
```

Maybe that is sufficient for you, if not please describe us your usecase in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function, that split the url by the components as stated in the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3)

```
$s = 'http://website.com/part1/part2/part3/detail/page_id/number/page/2';
$u = parse_url($s);

// gives you
array (size=3)
'scheme' => string 'http' (length=4)
'host' => string 'website.com' (length=11)
'path' => string '/part1/part2/part3/detail/page_id/number/page/2' (length=47)
```

In case you want to only get a specific component, the function can accept a flag as a second parameter (ex. `PHP_URL_PATH`) that helps on that.

```
$u = parse_url($s, PHP_URL_PATH);

// gives you
string '/part1/part2/part3/detail/page_id/number/page/2' (length=47)
```

You can now create an array of the segments, and elaborate your logic with it:

```
$segments = explode('/',trim($u,'/'));
```