# Get portion of URL with PHP

Tags: php

I had previously been using `basename` to grab the last part of my URL however have noticed some issues if my URL contains parameters.

So if my URL is this:
https://www.google.com/test-page/?utm_source=test

How would I pull `test-page` from this?

Comment: I'd use [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get parts of URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985505/get-parts-of-url-in-php)

Comment: Thank you so much both - fantastic help.

Answer (score 0):

You split it by the / delimiter, and then take the fourth item

```
$link = 'https://www.google.com/test-page/?utm_source=test';

$split = explode('/', $link);
if(isset($split[3]))
{
    echo $split[3];
}
```

Comment: Most of these basic tasks have already been covered on the site. Before posting an answer, do a quick search of the topic and if you find an existing solution, flag the question as duplicate. Don't get me wrong, it's good to see that you want to contribute, but the community prefers if we adhere to the site guidelines and avoid content duplication.

Comment: Apologies, is it possible that if my URL is `https://www.google.com/test-page/test-sub-page/?utm_source=test` then it would grab `test-sub-page` - so basically amend the function to get the data before the last slash?

Comment: Hey Michael, 

`$url = "https://www.google.com/test-page/test-sub-page/tester/?utm_source=test";

$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$parts = explode('/', $path);
$part = $parts[count($parts) - 2];

echo $part;`